# StartPosition is set to CenterPosition but my form is not centered

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, multiple-monitors

I'm using Visual Studio 2012. My form, when it opens doesn't center to the screen. I have the form's `StartPosition` set to `CenterScreen`, but it always starts in the top left corner of my left monitor (I have 2 monitors).

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Placing it in the constructor works for me. Would you show us some code?

Comment: Which code do you need to see. I was under the impression I could set this using the form's properties?

Comment: Both placing `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;` and setting it from the designer work for me. I've asked you for code to see if there's something that overwrites or interferes with your setting.

Comment: @user1936588 - ans updated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this way!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            //Method 1. center at initilization
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            //Method 2. The manual way
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            this.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - this.Height)/2;
            this.Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - this.Width)/2;

        }
    }
}
```

Two virtual members are called in constructor of the application.

namely

```
this.Text; 
this.MaximumSize;
```

do not call virtual member in constructor it may lead to abnormal behaviour

fixed code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            // to see if form is being centered, disable maximization
            //this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Convertor";
            this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 420); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither method 1 or 2 worked. This is the initialize code for form1 :- this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);
            this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 420);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Convertor";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

Comment: This worked for me, but not in the constructor. For some reason, form inheritance breaks `CenterScreen`, even after removing the inheritance that broke it. So the solution, for me at least, was to put the code from Method #2 in my base form's `Load` event handler.