# Center form during runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, centering

I've been developing a game. As such, I need to be able to display information that are group accordingly. I've been using a menu system that allows me to utilize 1 form to display different bits of grouped information using the panel control. Using a timer on the form, it automatically changes in size depending on just how much information is displayed, using the currently visible panel as a guide for dimensions.

I have the form's screen position behavior set to Center Screen. This works great.

However, there is a problem. The form is only truly centered when it is the size of the biggest panel - the log in screen - is active, being that it is the first menu a user sees.

My question is, using code, could I get the form to be re-centered during runtime? If so, how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the method [Form.CenterToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx)

or follow this answer!

[StartPosition is set to CenterPosition but my form is not centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293241/startposition-is-set-to-centerposition-but-my-form-is-not-centered)

Comment: This worked like a charm! I can't believe I couldn't find this. :s